# Wait for the child process to complete in system command in perl

Tags: perl

part of my script looks like this.

```
my @args = ("/bin/updateServer & ");
system (@args) == 0 or die "system @args failed: $?";
reloadServer;
```

My requirement is only after the updateServer finishes, reloadServer has to be called.
In my case reload server runs immeadiately after update server.
UpdateServer runs for around 4 hours and so I have to run it in background with "&"

How can I change my code to run reloadServer only after the updateServer is completed.

Can someone please help me in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
@args = ("/bin/updateServer");
```

Remove **&** from command to avoid start process in background

Comment: The question says it has to run in the background

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the `system` command in the background, create a [`thread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) to run it and then reload:

```
use threads;

my $thread = threads->create(sub {
    my @args = ("/bin/updateServer");
    system (@args) == 0 or die "system @args failed: $?";
    reloadServer;
});
# Store $thread somewhere so you can check $thread->error/is_running for it failing/completing.
# Continue doing other things.
```

The thread will run in the background and run `reloadServer` once the (now blocking) `system` command completes.

Comment: Thank You Rob, Will try out this. Also, I read that this can be done using fork, exec and wait, which way you think will be better ?